# Different audio output devices for simultaneous processes (Python + ffplay)

Tags: python, powershell, audio, ffplay

I have two mp3 files: `audio1.mp3` and `audio2.mp3`.

I am currently able to play them both at the same time by using Python subprocess and ***ffplay***.
(Using Windows' PowerShell currently, but answers regarding a Linux systems are also appreciated)

```
FFPLAY_EXE_PATH = "ffmpeg\\ffplay.exe"

subprocess.Popen(f"{FFPLAY_EXE_PATH} audio1.mp3", shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(f"{FFPLAY_EXE_PATH} audio2.mp3", shell=True)
```

I am also currently able to change my computer's audio output device through the PowerShell using ***AudioDeviceCmdlets***:

```
$ Get-AudioDevice -list  | ft Index, Default, Type, Name

Index Default Type      Name
----- ------- ----      ----
    1    True Playback  Speakers (Echo Dot-EMQ Stereo)
    2   False Playback  Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)
    3    True Recording Microphone Array (Realtek(R) Audio)


$ Set-AudioDevice -Index 2    # < Works fine
```

The big problem here is: if I change the output device (as shown in the last command), it changes it for everything currently running.

I would like to make it so that, while I am playing `audio1.mp3` in "AudioDevice 1", at the same time, play `audio2.mp3` through "AudioDevice 2".

A idea I've had was to somehow use stereo audio, but I'm not quite sure if that would work/how it would work.

Comment: You looking for solution only with `ffplay` ? any alternate solution also works?

Comment: What devices are visible to `ffplay --devices`? ffplay will use the default device if you don't explicitly tell it what device to use,

Comment: Not necessarily ffplay. Open to any alternatives.